# Google Cloud Internal Https Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have a use case to rollout our pre production systems internally and use certificates and https load balancer. Is it possible to use Google Https Load Balancer Internally?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: As of August 2019, GCP now offers an [Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/) solution. The load balancer is accessible only in the chosen region of your VPC network on a private, internal (RFC 1918) IP address. Note that it is currently in beta.

---

GCP doesn't currently (as of Feb 2019) offer an internal HTTP(S) Load Balancer solution. This may be made available in the future but there's no ETA at the moment.

Comment: What is the suggested way to use internally https?

Comment: Thanks @EladAmit but this is not something I want to deal with. I am switching AWS to Google Cloud. I am honestly surprised current state of GCP.

Comment: pros and cons to each cloud provider :)
there are quite a few gems in GCP which AWS is only now starting to beta in certain regions